# Onclick calls a variable into the data

Tags: javascript, variables, onclick

I have declared "branch" as a variable in the head. Its a JavaScript function that pulls down part of the url string that the function then declares as "branch". i.e.

pieshop.co.uk/bristol/buy

"branch" = bristol

the above works fine,

When a user clicks a button I want it to send some fixed figures and the variable "branch", the figures are sending correctly and so is the phrase "branch", but its not changing to the variable I have declared.

I have currently put this together,

```
<a href='http://www.google.com' onClick='function("1256", "468", "branch" );' target="_blank">send data</a>
```

How do i get this to pull in the "branch variable?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have sth. like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var branch = 'bristol';
  function myFunc(a, b, c){
    // do sth. with abc
    alert(c);
  }
</script>
```

you can:

```
<a href='http://www.google.com' onClick='myFunc("1256", "468", branch );' target="_blank">send data</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`"branch"` is a string literal, you can't assign anything to it. Take the quotes away if you want it to be a variable name.